# Is the anyway that I can plot bar and which I change the series?

Tags: pine-script

Is there anyway that I can plotbar with condition like this
plotbar(COND, Price1, price2), width -> plotbar(close>open, close, open), width
when the COND condition is satisfied, plot candle or bar line between the positions of PRICE1 and PRICE2, the width is WIDTH.
PLease help... I really need help on this... Please.

Comment: Hi Edwin, I would love to help out but I kindly ask you to reformulate your question. It is not really possible to understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you please be more specific? Thanks

Comment: Actually, I wish to plotbar where condition met, then it will plotbar between price1, and price2 to plor a bar, with certain (height, or width size given).
Plotbar(COND,PRICE1,PRICE2,WIDTH). 
eg, 
var_1=ema(X, 2)
_plotbar(var1>=var1[1], var_1, var_1[1]), linewidth=8, color=color.red_
Is the above possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.you can apply your condition on color transparency of the color you use in plotbar. for example :

```
c=(buy or sell)?color.rgb(255,255,0,0):color.rgb(255,255,0,100)
m=close*1.01
plotbar(m,m,m,m, color=c)
```